# Powershell script in sitecore content editor ribbon button taking so much time on first execution

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have created a custom button in the Sitecore content editor ribbon and I am calling a Sitecore Powershell script by using the command in the "Click" field  of button `item:executescript(script={6F54FCA3-F674-4D6A-9EBA-73A12B49F245},scriptDb=web)`
But this is taking so much time(around 5 min) when we execute it for the first time but when executes this second time then it doesn't take time at all. The Powershell script doesn't take time when I run it in Powershell ISE. Is there any way to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you share your script?